# Is it possible to remove the Exception Table (.pdata) when MSVC is generating a PE32+ file?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-c++, linker, x86-64

I was trying to get my x86-64 binary minimal sized with Visual Studio 2019.

It seems that both `x64` and `ARM64` output in the `PE32+` format have `.pdata` sections aka Exception Tables in them.

Searched a while, only found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/safeseh-image-has-safe-exception-handlers?view=msvc-160):

> /SAFESEH is only valid when linking for x86 targets. /SAFESEH is not supported for platforms that already have the exception handlers noted. For example, on x64 and ARM, all exception handlers are noted in the PDATA. ML64.exe has support for adding annotations that emit SEH information (XDATA and PDATA) into the image, allowing you to unwind through ml64 functions. See MASM for x64 (ml64.exe) for more information.

Is there a way of omitting `.pdata`?

Have tried with several other compiler/linker options but with no luck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev sorry for the typo. It's corrected now